# AWS - Reading file contents from a bucket using Angular 6

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm new to typescript and Amazon....

I need to fetch a file from an S3 bucket and display its contents (lets say readme.txt) in my view.

I've done up to fetching the object but can't find in typescript / angular  how to actually read the file. This sample

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

shows java example but it relies on buffer and stream reader which I don't think exist in angular ?

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Appreciate some guidance on where to go next - someone said I would have to use a directive ??

Just to clarify - I can get the data.Body but its a binary buffer - how do I get this back into text ?

Tks

Comment: Out of interest, are the contents of the bucket publicly available, or do you need to provide an API key?

Comment: They are private - I have provided the key, fetched the list of objects and identified any called readme.txt or similar - now I want to show the contents

Comment: It's a bad idea to do so from your Angular code, as it means your key can be viewed by anyone with access to the Angular app. If it's stored in the client code, it's publicly available. That said, if you really must do it, the documentation for the JS SDK is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)

Comment: Yes, that's where I started but it doesn't explain how to actually read the file contents - the link I added does, but I can't find the bufered reader.
As for security, its currently not an issue as the web site reading the bucket is only internal and user have to authenticate to use it anyhow..

Comment: According to those docs, on the callback function there is a `data` parameter, which itself has a `Body` property. Sounds like that may be what you're looking for. Bear in mind that even if users have to authenticate, the whole application source code will still be available to the browser, which contains your API key

Comment: Yes, I have that but the sample decodes that body using a byte reader - thats the but I'm struggling with  (we can discuss security later !)

Comment: Which sample? There's nothing on that page to do with a byte reader?

Comment: er, isn't buffered reader a byte reader of some kind ? See their displayTextInputStream method

Comment: That's the java SDK. Ignore the java SDK, you're not using Java.

Comment: I know - but that's the only sample I could find that reads the contents of the object  - hence the question !

Comment: Use the javascript example. Where it currently prints `console.log(data)`, why not try printing `console.log(data.Body)` and see where it gets you?

Comment: In their sample you call get object content and pass that into the binary reader. GetObjectContent says its undefined in the angular version.

Comment: That's because they're different SDKs, and trying to use methods from the java SDK in the javascript SDK will not work.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I think you are missing my point - the only sample I can find online is this Java one and I want to do it in Angular so trying to find equivalent approach in that SDK!

Comment: @Thiss if the only sample you can find is Java then you are searching wrong. Try looking at the AWS SDK for JavaScript.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, here is the code in Typescript.

As suggested in the docs, you can get the body from `data.Body`.

When I did so, I could see that `Body` was a `uint8array`, so we'll need to use `TextDecoder` to get this as a string.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

declare var TextDecoder;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    // Set up credentials
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: 'YOURKEY', secretAccessKey: 'YOURSECRET'
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'so-test-bucket',
      Key: 'index.html'
    };

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err); // an error occurred
      } else {
        const string = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.Body);
        console.log(string);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: If this solves the issue, please mark the answer as accepted so that others can find it in the future. Thanks

Comment: This introduces a security vulnerability because you are checking in your AWS secrets. How do you suggest doing this without having to check in your secrets?

Comment: What would you do here if you didn't want to check in your security credentials? I've been seeing this a lot where you add your creds in your code but that is a huge security vulnerability..